# IntelliJ indentation avoid using 2 tabs

Tags: java, intellij-idea, indentation

Something IntelliJ is using 2 tabs to indent code, but I really hate it, but I can't find where I can set this param in the settings.
An example of those cases are the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(
            () -> {} // as you can see this line of code is indented by 2 tabs
    );
}
```

Does anyone knows how to change this behavior?

Comment: It should be in the settings > Editor > Code Style > Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the settings, in the **Settings/Preferences** dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>), go to **Editor | Code Style** and choose language. You can set the settings you want there.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your time first of all, however I've already done this, but not option does what I'm asking for (at least, options that I can think of)

Comment: ok find it, it's literally the input field below the one that you are highlighting in the picture (if you want to mention it on your answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the **Tab size** and **Indent** in

`Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `[Language]`

[image: IntelliJ Edit Code Style]

Comment: thank you for your time first of all, however I've already done this, but not option does what I'm asking for (at least, options that I can think of)

Comment: ok find it, it's the "continuation indent" (if you want to mention it on your answer)